# Ocultando coluna inteira com CSS em uma resolução específica

Tags: css

Tenho uma tabela e preciso ocultar uma coluna inteira quando for aberto em uma resolução específica.

Tentei utilizar o `display: none` porém as bordas da tabela ficam aparecendo no fim da linha, mesmo se toda coluna for ocultada.

Tentei utilizar também o `visibility: hidden` e/ou `visibility: collapse`, porém só oculta o conteúdo, não oculta a coluna inteira.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Coloca o seu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escondendo apenas a terceira coluna a partir de `568px`.

Usando o `:nth-child(X)` você pode colocar o número da coluna que deseja ocultar.

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 568px) {
  table tr td:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi na sua citação, seria algo referente a isso?

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
.some {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Coluna A</td>
    <td>Coluna B</td>
    <td class="some">Coluna C</td>
    <td>Coluna D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Boa, to apredendo ainda a mexer aqui no stack, vlww!!

Comment: Sim Luiz Augusto, é isso que estou precisando, porém aplicando a técnica de resolução conforme o Diego Souza respondeu, fazendo assim, faz com que a coluna desejada, seja ocultada quando ficar em uma resolução específica. :D